# How do I get rid of background on a input.submit?

Tags: html, css, input, submit, background-image

I am currently trying to replace the input.submit button with an image. I have managed to do this successfully except there seems to be a background around the image which I want completely gone, and for it to just be the image.

Here is my css:

```
 {width:70px; height:40px; background:transparent url(images/shadow_search.png) no-repeat center top; overflow:hidden;}
```

(I've tried background:transparent to hide it, as well as overflow hidden?)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'll be just the border.

```
selector { border: 0; }
```

Should do.